# Как в svg анимации атрибут never работает?

Tags: svg, svg-animation

1. атрибут `restart` равный `always` перезапускает анимацию в любое время:

```html
<svg width="500" height="400" viewBox="0 0 500 400" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
 
<circle id='circ' r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />

<animate
xlink:href='#circ'
attributeName = 'cx'
restart='always'
from='50'
to='450'
dur='3s'
begin='click'
fill='freeze'

/>
```

2. атрибут `restart` равный `whenNotActive` не перезапускает анимацию когда анимация работает:

```html
<svg width="500" height="400" viewBox="0 0 500 400" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
     
    <circle id='circ' r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />

    <animate
    xlink:href='#circ'
    attributeName = 'cx'
    restart='whenNotActive'
    from='50'
    to='450'
    dur='3s'
    begin='click'
    fill='freeze'

    />
    </svg>
```

3. Что происходит когда атрибут `restart` равен значению `never`?

```html
  <svg width="500" height="400" viewBox="0 0 500 400" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
     
    <circle id='circ' r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />

    <animate
    xlink:href='#circ'
    attributeName = 'cx'
    restart='never'
    from='50'
    to='450'
    dur='3s'
    begin='click'
    fill='freeze'

    />
  </svg>
```

Comment: never - никогда, ни разу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**restart: never**: Элемент не может быть перезапущен, пока не будет перезагружен его родительский контейнер. (В случае с SVG, так как родительским контейнером является SVG-фрагмент документа, то анимация не может быть перезапущена, пока не перезагружен документ). 
Другими словами пока не нажмете F5, не перегрузите браузер, не перезапустите приложение, - анимация не запустится повторно.

В примере ниже анимация жёлтого круга запускается по первому клику на холсте svg.
 Анимация фиолетового круга запускается после окончания анимации желтого круга. `begin="an1.end+1s"`

Повторный клик будет проигнорирован. Ничего не произойдёт!

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="500" height="400" viewBox="0 0 500 400" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
     
    <circle id='circ1' r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />

    <animate id="an1"
    xlink:href='#circ1'
    attributeName = 'cx'
 restart='never'
    from='50'
    to='450'
    dur='1s'
    begin='svg1.click'
 fill="freeze"
   />
<circle id='circ2' r="50" cx="50" cy="200" fill="purple" />

    <animate id="an2"
    xlink:href='#circ2'
    attributeName = 'cx'
    from='50'
    to='450'
    dur='1s'
    begin='an1.end+0.5s'
    restart="whenNotActive" />
  </svg>
```

Потому что при повторном клике ни первая анимация, ни вторая анимация не запустится. Так как на первой стоит блокировка, а вторая анимация запускается только после окончания первой анимации.

*Допустим нам нужен следующий сценарий:*

1. При первом клике начинает движение желтый круг
2. Желтый круг заканчивает движение начинает движение фиолетовый круг
3. При втором и последующих кликах желтый круг не реагирует (стоит на блокировке), а фиолетовый круг при каждом клике начинает движение

Реализовать такой сценарий можно через прокладку - анимацию, которая ничего не делает, но помогает осуществить запуск анимации фиолетового круга при повторных кликах.

```html
 <svg id="svg1" width="500" height="400" viewBox="0 0 500 400" style='border: 1px solid black;'>
     
    <circle id='circ1' r="50" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />

   <!-- Анимация желтого круга   -->
  <animate id="an1"
    xlink:href='#circ1'
    attributeName = 'cx'
 restart='never'
    from='50'
    to='450'
    dur='1s'
    begin='svg1.click'/>
 
 <!-- Прокладка анимация, которая ничего не делает но помогает запустить -->
 <!-- анимацию фиолетового круга при повторных кликах  svg1.click -->
 <animate id="an2"
    xlink:href='#circ2'
    attributeName = 'cx'
 from='50'
    to='50'
    dur='0s'
    begin='an1.end;svg1.click'/>
 
   <circle id='circ2' r="50" cx="50" cy="200" fill="purple" />
  <!-- Анимация фиолетового круга -->
    <animate id="an3"
    xlink:href='#circ2'
    attributeName = 'cx'
    from='50'
    to='450'
    dur='1s'
    begin="an2.end+0.5s"
 restart="whenNotActive"
 />
  </svg>
```